# Chart.js can't update fontSize in Preact + Typescript

Tags: typescript, chart.js, preact

After siphoning through various posts and reading version history from Chart.js's github with no luck, I thought I'd throw this to the hivemind.

Using:
"preact": "^10.3.1",
"typescript": "^4.1.5"
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"@types/chart.js": "^2.9.30",

I am able to access the the fontSize property in all places (as far as VScode is concerned), including nested within the ticks.minor and ticks.major;

```js
   scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            suggestedMax: Math.max(...data) + 1,
                            fontSize: 20
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Seconds",
                            fontSize: 20
                        }
                    }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            minor: {
                                fontSize: 20
                            },
                            major: {
                                fontSize: 20
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

However any changes I make here do not work. I have tried running the chart.update() as below, to no avail also.

```
 chartToUpdate.options.scales?.yAxes?[0].ticks?.

const scaleAxes = chartToUpdate?.options?.scales?.xAxes;
const axesXTicks = scaleAxes && scaleAxes[0]?.ticks;
if (axesXTicks) {
    axesXTicks.minor = axesXTicks.major = {
        fontSize: 20
    };
}

chartToUpdate.update();
```

Has anyone else had this issue, and found a workaround? I simply have not been able to update the font sizes. Any help appreciated!

I have tried to reproduce on JSFiddle, however there is a slight difference in order to work with Typescript in my project; The first const declaration is followed by " as HTMLCanvasElement".

```
 const barChart = document.getElementById("barChart");
```

const answerHeaders =  ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];

const answerValues =  [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];

```
if (barChart !== null) {
    if (typeof myBarChart != "undefined") {
        myBarChart.destroy();
    }
    // myBarChart = generateBarChart(barChart, answerHeaders, answerValues);

    const ctx = barChart.getContext("2d") ? barChart.getContext("2d") : null;

    myBarChart = new Chart(barChart, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: answerHeaders,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Seconds",
                    data: answerValues,
                    backgroundColor: "#439c35",
                    borderColor: "#4a4a4a",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: "none",
                    lineTension: 0.1
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: {
                position: "bottom",
                display: false
            },
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: "Question Response Time"
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            suggestedMax: Math.max(...answerValues) + 1,
                            fontSize: 30
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Seconds",
                            fontSize: 40
                        }
                    }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            minor: {
                                fontSize: 20
                            },
                            major: {
                                fontSize: 20
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Result in dev (with dev data and custom gradient):
[image]

Comment: Do you have a reproducable sample of this because it seems to work fine with your config: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/6Lv07pab/4/

Comment: Thanks for the response @LeeLenalee, I am unable to reproduce in JSFiddle (it seems to work fine). I will add the code I ran on JSFiddle to my question, noting the difference required to run with typescript.